# is it possible to use vmdk format with ESXi 5.1

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have 700 GB VMDK VM and I want to use it with ESXi 5.1. I have searched the google and I got the impression that I need to export VMDK to first OVF format. I first tried it from Workstation it can hadle 1MB/sec so it s very slow and also I dont have space to convert 700 GB. So can I use VMDK VMs with ESXi 5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new virtual machine, and when the wizard gets to the step for hard drive(s), just say "use existing" instead of "create new", and point to the vmdk file.